# Vamp's training

Tags: metal-gear-solid-hd-collection, metal-gear-solid-series, metal-gear-solid-2-sons-of-liberty

In Metal Gear Solid 2 : Sons of Liberty 
Iroquois Pliskin(Snake) says Vamp is 
"a wizard with knifes"

Just curious, is this because Vamp is genetically modified or does he have some type of special training and if so what kind of training was it, i.e a type of martial art

Answer (score 3):

Vamp had quite a bit an out of the ordinary story.

So Vamp got his training in the **Navy SEALs anti-terrorist squad Dead Cell** for which he was a member. So basically about this skills with knives, guns, etc. that's all we know so far.

For his "supernatural" abilities well:

> Prior to his membership of the Navy SEALs anti-terrorist squad Dead
>   Cell, Vamp was subjected to experimental nanomachines, which would
>   allow him to heal from wounds and sickness at an unusually accelerated
>   rate. The nanomachines had previously been developed by Dr. Naomi
>   Hunter, and her design was later perfected by other interested
>   parties. The experiment proved to be a success, resulting in Vamp
>   gaining his apparent immortality. At some point later, Vamp joined
>   Dead Cell, and was one of the first members to join the unit during
>   its formation.

For additional information on Vamp you can check [Vamps Wiki Page](http://metalgear.wikia.com/wiki/Vamp)!

Comment: If someone is specifically asking for something, we don't do anyone a favor by not spoiling them.  They're asking, so answers should answer the question, not direct them elsewhere for their answer.

Comment: @Frank I thought about it and I edited my answer.

Comment: @Frank can you please tell me if is there anything I can improve on my answer?

Comment: I don't think summarizing a several page article in two lines does a whole lot to really answer the question.  Surely you can expand beyond, "His skills came from here, but he's also got nanomachines."

Comment: but @Frank there's nothing more to expand on. The wiki page has a lot of stuff. But about his training I exposed everything there. I'll edit so it is more clear.

Comment: @vaeu if by any chance you have seen this answer please consider accepting it to help other find it if they have questions similar to yours.